# Ionic emulate runtime error, but no details

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic3, cordova-3

Ionic serve works fine, no errors. But when running `ionic cordova emulate ios -lc`, an error message appears without any stack trace or detail. Nothing shows up in the console, either.

The error message in the emulator window is simply:

```
Error: Runtime error
```

How do I go about debugging this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the ionic generated Xcode project in Xcode from that path :

**Your_ionic_project/platforms/ios/**

Now build your Project and see the logs in Xcode console.

Comment: Thanks, there is no more info in the Xcode console. Had already tried that, but forgot to mention specifically that console in OP.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out Auth0 quickstart template code had returned an empty exception string. However, the error message was contained in their log.

Code producing the error:

```
client.authorize(options, (err, authResult) => {
  if(err) {
    throw err;
  }
```

When `err` was empty, nothing was shown by `IonicErrorHandler`.